# Find the number of zeros in $D(0;1)$ of $\cos \pi z -100z^{100}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

> Find the number of zeros in $D(0;1)$ of $\cos \pi z -100z^{100}$

The goal is to apply Rouché's Theorem to either $\cos \pi z$ or $-100z^{100}$. Here is what I did:

Let $f(z)=-100z^{100}$ and $g(z)=\cos \pi z$. Now
$$\begin{align*}
|\cos\pi z|&=\left \vert \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\pi z^{2n}}{(2n)!} \right \vert\\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(-1)^n|\frac{|\pi z|^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&= 1+\frac{\pi^2}{2!}+\frac{\pi^4}{4!}+\dots\\
&<1+\frac{4^2}{2!}+\frac{4^4}{4!}+\dots\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&=\cosh 4
\end{align*}$$
And on the other hand, $|f(z)|=|-100^{100}|=100$. Since $\cosh 4<100$, $f(z)$ has the same number of zeros that $f(z)+g(z)$ in $D(0;1)$, that is, $100$.

I don't know if the bound for $g$ is right, because Wolfram Alpha gives that the equation has two solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine. A slight nitpick is that in doing your estimates, you should mention you are considering $z$ on the boundary of the disc, i.e. $|z|=1$.

Now, there are two *real* solutions to your equation, which is what you probably found on WolframAlpha. If you ask it to search for complex roots of your equation, you will find many more solutions.